# Link key/button to the I'l feeling lucky from Play Music

Tags: autohotkey, google-music

so I always have a tab in Chrome opened with google play music, it's actually pinned so it's just there.

I'm wondering if there is any way to link a hotkey to the I'm feeling lucky option, I've been looking for quite some time but didn't find anything of help.

Button looks like this:

[image: I'm feeling lucky]

Thanks!

I've looked and asked on the AHK forums but don't know how many people are active there so thought I might give it a try here as well. Googled around but sadly didn't find anything of use or what I did find was a bit too complicated for me and didn't know how to apply it to what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward solution for this in AHK.

You need control over your browser in order to achieve this without interrupting your current navigation.

For controlling chrome with AHK: https://github.com/G33kDude/Chrome.ahk

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try these next days when I have a bit of time to read up on the docs. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple ways of doing this, but the easiest I can think of would be to use the `ImageSearch` command to get you the coordinates of the button and using `Click` or `MouseClick` to click the button.

If you're unfamiliar with the syntax or how to use these commands, please see the online documentation here: [ImageSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm), [MouseClick](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm), [Click](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm).

Please post your code if you need additional assistance and/or to help out others who might have the same or similar question in future.

Comment: This is not a viable option as the image is not on the screen, so using this method is not helpful. I do have it opened in a tab but it's sometimes minimized or not in focus. Thanks for the suggestions tho!

Comment: @David Is it okay to steal focus for a sec, then return focus to whatever had it?

Comment: No, I'm running certain things that take 30min to 1h to finish that need to stay in focus, I do have play/pause, next and prev set up for those cases. All that I'm missing is that magnificent button XD